# Problem with Receiver which receives Intents from Notification

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I have a code that send a broadcast to a broadcast receiver.

```
Intent intentPrev = new Intent(ACTION_PREV);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentPrev, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentPrev);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

In another class I have a `Receiver`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver NotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("PREVIOUS")){
                playPrev();
            }
        }
    };
```

And in `onCreate` method I register this receiver:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(NotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));
```

The main aim was to reach the following result: when user clicks on button Previous in notification, the previous song will play. But when I run the app and choose the music I can't listen to music, as always the previous plays. So, it seems that there's a perpetual loop somewhere. What's the matter? How to solve this problem if I want to play only one previous song but not all previous songs?

Comment: "And in onCreate method I register this receiver:" -- that will not work. A `PendingIntent` does not trigger a local broadcast.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so, does it mean, that I should create a special class `Receiver` and there are no other variants?

Comment: No, I mean that your `BroadcastReceiver` needs to receive system broadcasts, not local ones. For example, you could replace `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(NotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));` with `registerReceiver(NotificationReceiver, new IntentFilter("PREVIOUS"));`. There are limits on that too (for example, this won't work on Android 8.0+, as implicit broadcasts are banned), but it would be closer.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, thanks a lot! Sorry for my misunderstanding. Will you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of broadcasts: system broadcasts and local broadcasts.

Local broadcasts work through `LocalBroadcastManager` *exclusively*. If you see anything else tied to "broadcast", 99.99% of the time, that is referring to system broadcasts.

In particular, `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` gives you a `PendingIntent` that will send a system broadcast. That, in turn, means that your receiver needs to be set up to receive a system broadcast, either because:

- It is registered in the manifest with a `<receiver>` element, or
- It is registered dynamically by calling `registerReceiver()` on a `Context` (not on `LocalBroadcastManager`)

Note that on Android 8.0+, implicit broadcasts (ones with just an action string) are banned, in effect. If you elect to register your receiver in the manifest, use an `Intent` that identifies the specific receiver (e.g., `new Intent(this, MyReceiverClass.class)`). If you elect to register your receiver via `registerReceiver()`... I think there is a recipe for how to handle that, but I forget the details.